# WinAPI: How can I list shares connected by a UNC Path

Tags: winapi, remote-access, smb, unc

Using a UNC path such as `\\1.2.3.4\drive\dir\myfile.txt` I can access files on a remote machine.
I can make a connection using [WNetAddConnection2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2a) programatically
or I can just type `\\1.2.3.4\` in the explorer address bar, and then Windows will prompt me for user credentials etc.

How can I list the UNC drives that the local machine is connected to for the current user?

I tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wnet/enumerating-network-resources) example using [WNetEnumResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetenumresourcea) - it lists nothing I find useful.

I also found [this](https://www.installsetupconfig.com/win32programming/networkmanagementapis16_41.html) example using [NetShareEnum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmshare/nf-lmshare-netshareenum), but it seems only to list who is connected to a specified remote machine.

I want to list all UNC drives that the local machine is connected to (which must not have necessarily have a local drive letter).
How can that be done?

Comment: Network shares are a per-user configuration, not per system which you seem to expect.

Comment: You are right, thats what i want (connections for the current user) - i clarified my post accordingly.

Comment: What about `WNetEnumResource()` doesn't work for you? "*`RESOURCE_CONNECTED` - Enumerate all currently connected resources*", sounds like exactly what you are looking for. Please show the actual code you have tried so far.

Comment: Used the code of the linked sample - it doesnt show shared drives. I also tried RESOURCE_CONNECTED.

Comment: Do you mean to list such [drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STQaO.png)? [GetDriveType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypea)  can list network drive.

Comment: It wont LIST such entries. I have to pass a directory / drive letter.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. Please update some images or code to describe the drive letter or directory you need.